# linker command failed with exit code 1 with threads in c language

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, linker-errors

In my app I am getting this error :

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Below is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int sum;
void *runner(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t idw;  
    pthread_attr_t atrb; 

    pthread_attr_init(&atrb);
    
    pthread_create(&idw, &atrb,runner,argv[1]);
    
    pthread_join(idw,NULL);

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}
void *runner(void *param){
    int i;
    int up = atoi(param);
    sum=0;

    for (i = 1; i <= up; i++)
        sum+=i;

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I got

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_runner", referenced from:
> _main in main-ac5a24.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I am using macOS and version C language is C23.

Comment: Are you sure about your error message? Is it an actual full and complete copy-paste from the shown program? I sincerely doubt that. Possibly you could get similar messages about `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` if the `-pthread` flag is needed, but not about `runner`. Anyway, I [can't replicate the error](https://godbolt.org/z/aEo9cGGj1).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with Clang 14. I guess you build the wrong file (not up to date) where `void *runner(void *param);` is missing. Btw, C23 is not yet fully supported by Clang and not even yet recognized as such (see [here](https://clang.llvm.org/c_status.html)) but this is certainly unrelated to your problem.

Comment: what command did you use to compile and link your code?

Comment: I compiled with following command gcc main.c

Comment: And is `main.c` the *exact* code shown in this question?